essential supremum and equality with supremum for continuous function
I have found a fantastic proof continuity, essential supremum and supremum
but there is one thing that I don't get it
when in the proof there is written "For the reverse inequality, note that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|f(x)|>$ $M-\epsilon$."
I think it is using the definition of $\sup|f|=M$, but in my calculus course we have said that given a set $A$, $\sup A = L$ if $$\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists a \in A \text { s.t. } L-\epsilon \leq a$$ using $\leq$ instead of $<$.
edit : I actuall think is the same if there is the equal sign
edit 2 : also I think we shoul watch also case $M =0$ but I think this is trivial not ?
